RegEx to Shorten TripAdvisor Restaurant Review URLs
What RegEx can be used to shorten a TripAdvisor Restaurant Review URL from:
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g34515-d12538286-Reviews-Satu_li_Canteen-Orlando_Florida.html
to:
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g34515-d12538286
In other words, remove everything after "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g34515-d12538286"
Thank you!

...why do you want to use a regex?

It depends on the requirements. You could match everything up to the last digit that's followed by a hyphen... substitute ^(.*\d)-.* to captured $1. The first step is to think about the requirements - what separates the last part from the start, how can these urls possibly look like? (also include that into your question). Further mentioning the tool/environment will help to get an appropriate answer.

Try using this regex to match the part you wanna keep
^.+(-[a-z]\d+){2}

or this one to replace to empty string
-Reviews.+$

